# cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types

Tags: rust

I have a struct which I need to convert to byte buffer. Currently I'm using `bytemuck` crate to get this done, but I'm getting an error

```
#[derive(bytemuck::NoUninit, Clone, Copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Data {
    pub msg_id: u16,

    pub id: [u8; 128],

    pub a: f64,
    pub b: f64,
    pub c: f64,
    pub d: f64,
    pub e: f64,
    pub f: f64,
    pub g: f64,
}

fn main() {
    
}
```

Error

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
 --> src/main.rs:3:12
  |
3 | pub struct Data {
  |            ^^^^
  |
  = note: source type: `Data` (1536 bits)
  = note: target type: `TypeWithoutPadding` (1488 bits)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0512`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

Comment: Why are you marking your type as `NoUninit` when it has padding?

Comment: @isaactfa it is required by this bound in `bytes_of` method of `bytemuck`

Comment: Hmm, you could add the padding yourself: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=915c9537afcf31a2b19b6a0ae0c65b9f But I'll have a look if bytemuck has a different api for this

Answer (score 2):

You have 130 bytes of data followed by a `f64`, which has alignment 8. 130 mod 8 = 2, so (per [the `repr(C)` layout rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#reprc-structs)) there will be padding bytes placed between `id` and `a`. Padding bytes are always uninitialized, so they do not qualify for being `bytemuck::NoUninit`.

You must change your struct declaration so that it actually does not have uninitialized bytes. In some cases, you could do this by reordering the fields, but here that would leave you with padding at the *end* of the struct (because in Rust, a type's size is always a multiple of its alignment). Therefore, you will have to insert 6 bytes of explicit “padding”, so that the total byte size of the fields before the first `f64` is a multiple of 8:

```rust
pub struct Data {
    pub msg_id: u16,
    pub _padding: [u8; 6],

    pub id: [u8; 128],

    pub a: f64,
    pub b: f64,
    pub c: f64,
    pub d: f64,
    pub e: f64,
    pub f: f64,
    pub g: f64,
}
```

This `_padding` field can be set to `[0; 6]` or whatever value you like; the important thing is that the language considers it to *have* a specific value, not be uninitialized, which is the property that `bytemuck::NoUninit` requires.

Of course, if you can find a *use* for those extra bytes, or a way to remove 2 bytes, that's even better.